# CMD.exe has two different PATH

Tags: windows-7, path, cmd, environment-variables, windows-7-x64

So when I open the command prompt with RUN (Windows key + R, type cmd) I get this path (which is the good one) :

```
PATH=C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Program File
s (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA
 Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbe
m;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Liv
e\Shared;C:\Ruby193\bin
```

The problem is that when I directly open C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe or hold shift and right click in a folder and "Open command window here" I get this path (which is old and outdated):

```
PATH=C:\Ruby200\bin;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Program Fil
es (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windo
ws\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x
86)\Windows Live\Shared;C:\Ruby200\devkit\bin;C:\Ruby200\devkit\mingw\bin
```

Both prompt are opened as Administrator, they both show the same title (Administrator: C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe).

Anyone have an idea on how to fix that ?

Thanks

Comment: In case anyone runs across this wondering why a cmd.exe instance started by their program doesn't have the latest %PATH%: Restart your program (and maybe your IDE).  

Environment variables are passed like genes: If the user opens cmd.exe, cmd gets the latest vars from Explorer.  If your _application_ opens cmd.exe, cmd gets whatever vars your application received when _it_ opened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checking the path :

```
reg query "HKCU\Environment" /v Path
reg query "HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment" /v Path
```

The [GUI way](http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm) :

- Win+Pause keys
- Advanced system settings
- Environment Variables button
- Check `Path` value in System variables.

Checking any starting script for CMD :

```
reg query "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor" /v AutoRun
reg query "HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor" /v AutoRun
```

Searching anywhere in the Registry :

```
reg query "HKCU" /s|find /i "C:\Ruby200"
reg query "HKLM" /s|find /i "C:\Ruby200"
```

Obvious advice : restart your computer if you just uninstalled Ruby 2.0.